# How to change the screen gamma-curve?

Tags: screen, settings

Where can I change the gamma-curve of my monitor under Ubuntu? I can't find it under systemsettings.

I'm using a Lenovo Thinkpad Edge 130.

Comment: Does the monitor itself not have a button that does that?

Comment: Only the brightness. No contrast/gamma.

Comment: I know that nVidia provide gamma controls with their drivers with nvidia-settings.

Could you tell us what hardware you have?

Comment: @Drac Noc I have a Lenovo Thinkpad Edge 130 i3.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the specs, you have an Intel 3000HD chip?

If so, using

```
xgamma -gamma x.x
```

where *x.x* is the value should help you out. Setting x.x at 1.0 is the default, 1.2 should brighten things up a bit.

You can also spec the colour channels using

`-rgamma -bgamma -ggamma`

for red, blue and green respectively.

Comment: Thank you, that worked well. Would be neat if Ubuntu could integrate this into the settings. (i3-3217U)